# Making queries that involves ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django

Apologies on the last question. Should have phrased it better.

I have three classes, Student and another Adult and AdultProfile. I would like to make a query such that it gets all the adults who are from US  but it has to be done using Student class. This is because my queryset is Student.objects.all() and based on this queryset, i would like to get all the adults(through AdultProfile) from US . This is an example of the code while the original code much more complex and longer. This example shows the gist of the problem.

```
class Student(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   birthday= models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)

class Adult(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   parent= models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name="relationships")

class AdultProfile(models.Model):
   country = models.CharField(max_length=2)
   adult = models.OneToOneField(Adult,related_name='profile')
```

Need some help in this.. Hope i have phrased it better this time...

Comment: Why didn't you edit the previous question rather than delete it and add a new one?

Comment: i wanted to ask another thing, so if i edited it, those who answered will complain....

Comment: People who answered would be more disappointed that the question was deleted. Anyway, it's not a bad question by any means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this from a `Student` queryset. The only way you will end up with Adult objects from a Student class is from a **Student instance** via its reverse-related-accessor: `student_instance.relationships.all()`.

The missing ingredient in your django ORM travels is probably the fact that you can query related objects (FK, OneToOne) via its `related_name` (or by default, the model name).

```
student_qs = Student.objects.all() # some query
adults_in_us = Adult.objects.filter(parent__in=student_qs, profile__country='US')
```